# Manage pairs of servers with Ansible

Tags: ansible

My setup contains "pairs of servers" in the sense that every "instance" of my service consists of two servers (say database and web) on (usually) different hosts. That is, I don't have a single database server that many web servers talk to -- instead, each web server talks to its own database server. I want to manage multiple such pairs, but I don't know the best way to model the pairs using Ansible.

The main host organization tools in Ansible seem to be groups and roles. However, these only group together hosts of the same kind. I can use that to, for example, set up the necessary software on my database and web servers. However, I don't think I can use groups or roles to tell every web server to use exactly one of the database servers.

It also makes little sense to use an Ansible group to model one server pair, since I then cannot distinguish between the two different roles in these groups.

Although my setup consists of server pairs I'd also be interested in modeling multiple instances of `n`-to-`m` host relations (say `n` database servers and `m` web servers) in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following approach: Each pair of servers gets their own group, and group variables are used to define which server runs on which host:

```
[test]
test-host

[test:vars]
web_server = test-host
db_server = test-host

[production]
web
db

[production:vars]
web_server = web
db_server = db
```

The tasks for web and database servers are then put into separate roles (`web_server` and `db_server`). I then switch between those roles based on the group variables:

```
- hosts: all
  roles:
     - { role: web_server, when: "web_server == inventory_hostname" }
     - { role: db_server, when: "db_server == inventory_hostname" }
```

This setup allows me to easily define shared variables for roles and pairs, and it also allows me to easily target just one pair (via `--limit`).

Answer (score 2):

You could just use ansible variables to provide the necessary links.  E.g., in your inventory:

```
[webservers]
web0 dbserver=db0
web1 dbserver=db1

[dbservers]
db0
db1
```

Now, when running tasks on your web servers, you can simply refer to the `dbserver` variable to find the appropriate server.  Assuming a standard naming scheme, you could automate this through the use of the `set_fact` module.

**Update**

You don't need to specify the links in both directions; you could use
something like this to find the webservers which should have access to
a given database server:

```
- name: allow access to webserver
  command: >
    iptables -A INPUT
    -s {{hostvars[item].ansible_default_ipv4.address}}
  with_items: "{{groups.webservers}}"
  when: "hostvars[item].dbserver == {{inventory_hostname}}"
```

Comment: This works, but is rather cumbersome: First I need the information in both directions (e.g. to allow remote access from the web server on the database server), so I need to add `webserver=...` to each database server, which is redundant information and makes maintenance harder. Secondly there is no nice way to share variables between the web and database servers (e.g. database user names) because variables are defined globally, per group or per play.

Comment: I think you could avoid the redunant information by using `hostvars` to locate the appropriate webserver, rather than having to record this explicitly in your inventory (e.g., search for a webserver that has `dbserver=<this database server>`).  You can absolutely share information like database user names by declaring them in a common role, and including that in any plays in which you need the information.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I ended up using a different approach (see my answer), but I do appreciate your input!